# Append same text to label when button is pushed multiple times

Tags: ios, swift

I want to append text to a label when a button is pushed. And when the button are pushed again, I want the same text to be added in a new line in the label.

```
var someText = "text"

@IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    label.text = someText
}
```

When I do this the label only is printing:
text.

If the button is pushed 3 times, I would like the label to print: "text" - new line - "text" - new line - "text"

Or.
3x text

How should I go about to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As Matt stated, you would need to use programming.  Just take the string that is in the label and append a new line with the new text.  I didn't test this code, but it would be something like this:

```
// variable for the "text"
var someText = "text"

@IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // if the label text is empty, do not append a new line character
    if label.text?.isEmpty {
        label.text = someText
    } else {
        // if the label contains text, append a new line character and add the new text
        label.text += "\n" + someText
    }
}
```